# Pointfree version doesn't compile, but the pointful one does?

Tags: haskell, types, pointfree, function-composition, combinators

I want to write a Haskell function that returns a list appended to itself count times (like `lst * count` in Python).

My first attempt is:

```
self_append_n :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
self_append_n = concat . replicate
```

My reasoning is that `replicate` accepts a count and a value, and produces a list of values. When the value is itself a list, all that remains is to concatenate the lists together. However, this gives a bewildering error:

```
Couldn't match type `[a0]' with `[a] -> [a]'
Expected type: [[a0]] -> [a] -> [a]
  Actual type: [[a0]] -> [a0]
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `concat'
In the expression: concat . replicate
In an equation for `self_append_n':
    self_append_n = concat . replicate
```

Then I wrote a pointful version:

```
self_append_n a b = concat $ replicate a b
```

and it works!

Why does the point-free version fail to compile, but adding points makes it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It probably helps to explicitly parenthesise the signatures:

```
selfAppend :: Int -> ([a]         -> [a])
replicate  :: Int -> ([a]->[[a]])
concat     ::          [[a]]      -> [a]
```

If you try to compose `concat . replicate`, you end up giving `concat` the partially appied result of `replicate`, i.e. `[a] -> [[a]]`. That doesn't unify with `[[a]]`.

What you need to do is first pass *both* arguments to `replicate` before handing on the result. IMO best way to do that is "semi-pointfree":

```
selfAppend n = concat . replicate n
```

Less readable alternatives would be

```
selfAppend' = curry $ concat . uncurry replicate
selfAppend'' = (concat.) . replicate
```

Or with the infamous operator

```
(.:) :: (c->d) -> (a->b->c) -> a->b->d
(.:) = (.).(.)
 -- `≡ fmap fmap fmap`, also a popular implementation...
```

you can simply write

```
selfAppend''' = concat .: replicate
```

Comment: I get it. The composition fails because the actual return type of replicate is not a list, but a function (which itself returns a list).

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, Haskell's _curry everything_ philosophy is not always a benefit (though very often it is).